# 'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'

Tags: python, string

I'm probably being really dumb here, but I can't figure out this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
```

This occurs on the line:

```
docLines[counter][counter2] = [(docLines[counter][counter2]).translate(None, string.punctuation)]
```

Where docLines[counter][counter2] is just a single word.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with is line of  code?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this line?

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned that, I'm trying to remove punctuation from all the words in the lists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: The question wasn't asking how to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've assigned a string (instance of `str`) to a variable named `string`. Rename the variable and the problem will go away.

To debug this, add `print repr(string)` before the offending line and it will print a string instance. A number of such prints in various places in your module will help you discover where the name `string` stopped referring to the `string` module and started referring to a `str` instance.

Comment: This is perfect, but it's marginally worth noting that he also has to import the string module, if he has not already.

Comment: I assumed the OP knows that, or if not, the `NameError` will guide him in the right direction. The error he did get, on the other hand, is quite confusing and not at all helpful if one doesn't already understand what's going on.

Comment: Good point, I suppose it's pretty unlikely he'd be using string.punctuation if he _didn't_ already know it comes from the string module.

Comment: I have been importing string, yes. I don't have any variables called string that I can see though.

Comment: Add `print repr(string)` before the offending line and you'll see that it prints a string. A number of such prints in various places in your module will help you discover where the name `string` stopped referring to the `string` module and started referring to a `str` instance.

Comment: @Incredidave I've now edited the answer to include the debugging tip from my last comment.

Comment: I'll try that now, thanks. I suspect the problem will be that I'm reading in a file then using .readlines() and .split() to turn it into a list of lines, each of which is a list of words.

Comment: hmm, no matter where I put it it just seems to return the name of the text doc I read in.

Comment: @Incredidave Even if the first line of your script is `import string` and the second line `print repr(string)`? In that case output should begin with `<module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py'>`. At the place in your script when `print repr(string)` stops printing that line, you've found your bug. If the script doesn't contain an `import string` statement at all, you're dealing with two bugs.

Comment: @Incredidave: can you not just search for exact token `string`? You question is resolved, we cannot possibly read minds.

Comment: @user4815162342 I managed to fix it with your advice, thanks a lot.